# Process.start() não inicia corretamente outro aplicativo

Tags: c#

Olá. Tenho uma solução composta por três aplicativos. Um deles é um serviço do Windows (**BoardService.exe**). Outro é um aplicativo Windows Forms que abre uma tela de apresentação e cria um ícone na bandeja do relógio do Windows (**BoardPlayer.exe**). O terceiro aplicativo é o **BoardMonitor.exe** (console application) cuja função é iniciar o serviço do windows (BoardService.exe) caso ele pare e iniciar o BoardPlayer.exe caso este seja fechado pelo usuário. A idéia é fazer isso sem que uma janela de linha de comando seja exibida.

Para tanto criei uma tarefa agendada do windows que roda a cada 3 minutos e chama o aplicativo BoardMonitor.exe.

Agora vem o meu problema: Executando o aplicativo BoardMonitor.exe manualmente, o aplicativo BoardPlayer.exe é iniciado corretamente, porém quando executado através da tarefa agendada, o aplicativo BoardPlayer.exe passa a aparecer no Gerenciador de tarefas do Windows porém ele não abre as telas e nem aparece na bandeja do relógio. Vejam o código do aplicativo BoardMonitor.exe:

```
namespace BoardMonitor
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Verifica se o aplicativo BoardPlayer.exe está executando
                Process processo = Process.GetProcessesByName("BoardPlayer").FirstOrDefault();

                if (processo == null)
                {
                    using (Process p = new Process())
                    {
                        // Todos os aplicativos estão na mesma pasta                            
                        p.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "BoardPlayer.exe");
                        p.Start();

                        SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
                    }

                    Log.RegistraMensagem("Processo BoardPlayer.exe chamado pelo BoardMonitor.exe", TipoEvento.Alerta);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.RegistraMensagem("Erro ao verificar se o aplicativo BoardPlayer.exe está rodando." + ex.Message, TipoEvento.Erro);
            }

            // Trecho que inicia o serviço
        }
    }
}
```

Imagino que o problema esteja ao setar as propriedades de StartInfo, porém, não sei como proceder. Já procurei o que podia na web e encontrei várias soluções mas nenhuma delas me ajudou.

Agradeço desde já pela ajuda recebida.

Comment: Achei a solução para o problema da pergunta no link (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0c0ca087-5e7b-4046-93cb-c7b3e48d0dfb/how-run-client-application-as-a-windows-service-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral).